# NodeJS mongoClient invalid operator: $eq

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a mongo property (category), where I want to filter with equals.
I used the following syntax:

```
{"category":{"$eq":"cat1"}}
```

(I know, it can be written like:

```
{"category":"cat1"}
```

If I use the $eq operator, the mongoClient fails with "invalid operator: $eq". But only on localhost.
If I deploy the same code to a remote server, it works perfectly.

How can I make it work on localhost?
It would be preferred to use the $eq operator - there are many places in the code where this is used.

Thx

Comment: hmm... 
mongo --version
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9
I guess you are right

Comment: yep... updated local instance, and it works perfectly (copy your comment as an answer so I can set it as solution). Thx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`$eq` query operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/) was introduced in version 3.0, but it seems to also work on my local 2.6.7 install.

So you likely just need to update your local install.

Comment: But the official docs says "New in version 3.0."
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/